# Exclude Inverse Relationship from Core Data Fetch Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

Parent Object has a to many relationship to it's self as it's children.

[image: Core Data Model]

When I fetch all the children of an object, the request also returns the parent object via the inverse relationship.

Is there a way within a fetch request to exclude the inverse relationship so that the result will only contain the children objects?

My solution thus far has been to implement a method within the custom NSManagedObject class for Object that returns a filtered array of the children.

```
-(NSArray *)getChildrenOfObjectWithoutParent:(int)parentId
{
    NSArray *results = [[self.children allObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(objId != %d)", parentId]];
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cleaner solution would be to have two relationships:

- `children` as *to-many* relationship from *Object* to itself,
- `parent` as *to-one* relationship from *Object* to itself

and define these as mutual inverse relationships.

Then `self.children` gives exactly the child objects, without any problems or tricks.

[image]

(I assume from your description that an object can have only one parent. If an object has multiple parents, you would define `parent` also as *to-many* relationship.)

Another advantage of this setup is that you can define the different Core Data "Delete Rules" for the relationship.

One useful example is:

- delete rule "Cascade" for the `children` relationship, and
- delete rule "Nullify" for the `parent` relationship.

The effect would be that if one object is deleted, all its children objects are also deleted automatically, and the object is removed from the parent objects children.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! An additional benefit; I am using this model for hierarchical navigation and I was previously keeping a parentFolderStack property to facilitate backwards navigation, now I can just fetch on the parent relationship. Thanks again.